# Tables with row and column headers

Tags: javascript

I feel like an idiot asking this question but does anyone know of a good javascript library to create a table with headers for the row and column? Im looking for something that works like this:

[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: This can be done with pure css only. Just use `<th></th>` for the header...

Answer (score 8):

You can HTML and CSS to do this.

This is a draft of a table with your specifications.

```html
 <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th>header 1</th>
        <th>header 2</th> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>col 1</th>
        <td>data1</td> 
        <td>data2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

our style should be then determined in css.

Answer (score 4):

something like this can be done via css and html

```css
td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.invisible {
    border: none;
    background-color:transparent;
}
.leftHeader {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color:lightgray;
}
th {
    background-color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="invisible"></th>
            <th>Top Header</th>
            <th>Top Header</th>
            <th>Top Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftHeader">Left Header</td>
            <td>Normal Cell</td>
            <td>Normal Cell</td>
            <td>Normal Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftHeader">Left Header</td>
            <td>Normal Cell</td>
            <td>Normal Cell</td>
            <td>Normal Cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```